# How should I organize my git branches in this context?

Tags: git

I'm working on feature A. It needs to be merged into master by *date*.

I'm working on feature A'. It depends on A but can be merged later than *date*.

How should I organize myself?

Comment: This is really a matter of opinion.  I assume you mean that A and A' are being worked on simultaneously.  Branch both A and A' from master, merge A into master at the appropriate time and merge that master back into A' at that time - therefore your merge of A' into master will be easier and will incorporate A.  Nothing prevents you from merging branches arbitrarily in git anyhow.  Organize as you need to organize it.

Comment: I'm not sure about this because A' won't have A until I merge A into master.

Comment: I just said that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Branch A off master. Branch A' off A.

```
1 - 2 - 3 [master]
         \
          4 - 5 - 6 [A]
                   \
                    7 - 8 - 9 [A']
```

As A gets worked on, rebase A' onto the new A.

```
1 - 2 - 3 [master]
         \
          4 - 5 - 6 - 11 - 12 [A]
                   \
                    7 - 8 - 9 [A']

git checkout A'
git rebase A

1 - 2 - 3 [master]
         \
          4 - 5 - 6 - 11 - 12 [A]
                             \
                              7A - 8A - 9A [A']
```

If master gets worked on and A needs to rebase onto the new master, it will have to be careful to also update A'.

If the people doing the merging understand Git, there's no need for any special naming convention. The geometry of the repository will make the dependency obvious. Nobody should be blindly merging branches without first talking to who is working on it anyway.

If they don't, maybe name A `feature/something_descriptive` and then A' is `feature/something_descriptive/more_description` to reflect the dependency.

Once A is merged into master, simplify things by rebasing A' onto master and continue development on A'.

```
git checkout master
git merge A
git branch -d A

1 - 2 - 3 --------- 10 [master]
         \         /
          4 - 5 - 6
                   \
                    7 - 8 - 9 [A']

git checkout A'
git rebase master

1 - 2 - 3 --------- 10 [master]
         \         /  \
          4 - 5 - 6    7A - 8A - 9A [A']
```

Then A' can be merged normally.

Answer (score 1):

I'd fork master to create A, then fork A to create A'. You can pull other trunk commits up into the branches as needed, and merge A back into master without merging A' into A (or into master).

Comment: I would avoid using concepts of "trunk" in git, but this is a good answer.  If A' depends on A, you could branch it from A when A is ready to spawn A'.  The point is that branches and merges can be relatively arbitrary depending on history of commits.  It is really important to grasp this since folks work individual repos and even forks but you will still need to merge code ultimately.  We often start a feature before the dependency is ready (it uses stubs) then merge the feature when it is good - since both branches share a common ancestor, it works very well.  But it is a matter of opinion.

Comment: Are you sure you meant "fork" and not "branch"?

Answer (score -1):

Mix your pending work on a single branch, interactive rebase to put the `A` stuff that's ready to  merge before the `A'` stuff that isn't, merge the `A` stuff.

Comment: -1 While this will work, it invites a tangled mess. It's something you do when you didn't realize beforehand that you have two dependent branches. By leaving it to the end it invites the two sets of changes to get tangled together, including tests and documentation. Commits might have to be pulled apart, and there are going to be conflicts. Better to develop them in the correct order from the start and consider the problem incrementally.

Comment: @Schwern It also means that you can work on your `A` code while still having the `A'` code that depends on it in the worktree, available for inspection and testing, I find rebasing when it'll help me think clearly is the best way to help me think clearly  Also, this way's more efficient by every metric; even when it's best to lockstep the work, doing commit-rebase to add to the `A`  work is both cleaner and quicker than doing checkout-commit-checkout-rebase.

Comment: Testing and inspecting the tangled branch doesn't mean much because that branch will never be merged. A and A' will be merged. The process of untangling A and A' can introduce so much change that each will have to be tested and reviewed again. The "efficiency" of having everything tossed into one branch comes at the cost of added complexity and risk at the end, right when you want to be reducing risk. Splitting a branch in two is a very complicated and risky process. If you like having two working trees at the same time, use [`git-worktree`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-worktree).

Comment: Furthermore, it makes it difficult for anyone else to work on the branch. They have to carefully learn and remember what parts are A and what parts are A'. It's *very* easy to make A depend on A'. Again, you only find this out when you're "done" and have to untangle the branch, putting the risk and complexity at the end. And its difficult to know when you're ready to untangle; if A' is incomplete that can introduce instabilities and complexity in testing even though A would be ready to go if it were its own branch.

Comment: Crossing the street's dangerous too. Less for some than for others.